# Should "Prenuptial agreement" be provided while getting marriage licence?

Tags: united-states, california, marriage, divorce, prenuptial-agreement

If two person want to get married and both are agree with writing a "Prenuptial  agreement", should they provide it while they want to get their marriage license or there is no need to provide this agreement anywhere except at the court maybe they want to get divorce a day?

If they write an agreement by themselves and sign it together( either before or after marriage), will this paper work at the court in the future when they want to get divorce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To supplement the correct [answer by user6726](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/80191/17500):

There is no need anywhere in the US to file a prenuptial agreement with  county clerk or any other part of the government when applying for a marriage license, or at any time before the wedding. It is a private agreement, and there is no need to show it to anyone but the parties concerned, and their lawyers (if any), until and unless one party wishes to invoke it, normally in the event of a divorce or separation.

The exact requirements vary by state, but in all stats it is often wise to consult a lawyer for each party. If one or both parties do not consult a lawyer in regard to a "prenup", then it is important to carefully follow the specific law of the state(s) where the parties are now living   pr plan to live. Failure to do so may make the agreement unenforceable.

Comment: If the couple decides to have prenup, and they go separately to their different legal counsels, and after 7 days they both sign the agreement( as my understanding of California state law about prenup agreement to be valid), shouldn't they provide/submit this agreement anywhere/anytime until and unless one party wishes to invoke it, normally in the event of a divorce or separation?

Comment: @GoodMan I do not know of a procedure by which it is even possible for either party, or both together, to submit a prenup agreement to any governmental entity to be registered or recorded. I have not heard of this being done.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. May I also ask if there is any time period/limitation couples can have prenup agreement before their marriage? I mean they must sign it at most 6 months before the marriage date for example.

Comment: @GoodMan The agreement is subject to the ordinary statute of limitations on a contract. I am not sure how long that is in California, but it must be several years at least. That limit is tolled (paused) during the marriage.

Answer (score 4):

There is no [requirement in California](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displayText.xhtml?lawCode=FAM&division=4.&title=&part=5.&chapter=2.&article=2.) to file a prenuptial agreement before obtaining a license. There is a requirement for disclosure of property and finances, 7 days minimum to review the agreement and being represented by a lawyer or waiving representation, specifically:

> The party against whom enforcement is sought was represented by
> independent legal counsel at the time of signing the agreement or,
> after being advised to seek independent legal counsel, expressly
> waived, in a separate writing, representation by independent legal
> counsel. The advisement to seek independent legal counsel shall be
> made at least seven calendar days before the final agreement is
> signed.

It is possible for a couple to write their own agreement without hiring separate lawyers, but the law is written so as to presume that if not advised by independent counsel, the agreement is unenforceable. The presumption can be overcome by carefully following the requirements of §1615, for example, the party against whom the agreement is to be enforced was

> fully informed of the terms and basic effect of the agreement as well
> as the rights and obligations the party was giving up by signing the
> agreement, and was proficient in the language in which the explanation
> of the party’s rights was conducted and in which the agreement was
> written. The explanation of the rights and obligations relinquished
> shall be memorialized in writing and delivered to the party prior to
> signing the agreement. The unrepresented party shall, on or before the
> signing of the premarital agreement, execute a document declaring that
> the party received the information required by this paragraph and
> indicating who provided that information.

Comment: If the couple decides to have prenup, and they go separately to their different legal counsels, and after 7 days they both sign the agreement( as my understanding of California state law about prenup agreement to be valid), shouldn't they provide/submit this agreement anywhere/anytime until and unless one party wishes to invoke it, normally in the event of a divorce or separation?